# Find all the value of $(x, y, z)$ with $x, y, z \in \Bbb R$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

$$x^2 + 4 = y^3 + 4x - z^3$$
$$y^2 + 4 = z^3 + 4y - x^3$$
$$z^2 + 4 = x^3 + 4z - y^3$$

What's the proper method to solve this question? I've tried any method but still not get the answer.

Comment: $x=y=z=2$ is one solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summing up the three equations we obtain

$$(x-2)^2 + (y-2)^2 + (z-2)^2 = 0$$

which is true if and only if each term is equal to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2 + 4 = y^3 + 4x - z^3 \implies x^2 -4x +4 = y^3-z^3 \implies (x-2)^2 = y^3-z^3 \quad\text{ (1.)}$$

$$y^2 + 4 = z^3 + 4y - x^3 \implies y^2 -4y +4 = z^3 -x^3 \implies (y-2)^2 = z^3-z^3 \quad\text{ (2.)}$$

$$z^2 + 4 = x^3 + 4z - y^3 \implies z^2 -4z +4 = x^3-y^3 \implies (z-2)^2 = x^3-y^3 \quad\text{ (3.)}$$

Adding all three equations:

$$(x-2)^2 + (y-2)^2 + (z-2)^2 = 0$$

$$x-2 = 0 \,\,,\,\, y-2 = 0\,\,,\,z-2=0$$

$$\boxed{x=y=z=2}$$